# Parse nested elements in an xml using jaxb

Tags: java, android, xml, jaxb

I am currently learning how to parse xml files using Jaxb in android. But i have no clue what is wrong in the code, and where and how to correct it. I am not able to parse the xml and get the list of food items. If i remove List and simply write it as Food then only the last element in the xml is parsed, the rest seem to be overwritten. Please help me.

I am trying to parse http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml, and so far i have this code:

---- CODE FOR UNMARSHALLING THE XML

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml");
InputSource is = new InputSource(url.openStream());
is.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(BreakfastMenu.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
BreakfastMenu menu = (BreakfastMenu)jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(is);
```

----- The classes look as under
----- Breakfast.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name="breakfast_menu")
public class BreakfastMenu {
private List<Food> food = new ArrayList<Food>();

public List<Food> getFood() {
    return food;
}

@XmlElement(name="food")
public void setFood(List<Food> food) {
this.food = food;
}
```

}

--- The food class

```
@XmlRootElement(name="food")
public class Food {
private String name;
private String description;
private String calories;

public String getName() {
return name;
}

@XmlElement
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

// same for description and  calories

P.S: I have tried [this link too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14658921/xml-unmarshalling-using-jaxb)
Thanks.

Comment: Android does not have JAXB.

Comment: Yes sir, it doesnt but i referred to plutext, that has the jaxb source repackaged, (they use it for android docx to html conversion), so i managed to repackage the entire source into one that is working and using it in android, with references to openbeans since java.beans is also not allowed in android

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It feels great solving the problem. To anyone else who might end up facing the same problem: here is the solution:

I changed the BreakfastMenu.class to

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="breakfast_menu")
public class BreakfastMenu {


@XmlElement(name="food", type=Food.class)
private List<Food> food  = new ArrayList<Food>();

public List<Food> getFood() {
    return food;
}

public void setFood(List<Food> food) {
this.food = food;
}
}
```

Whilst in the Food.class i removed the @XMLElement annotations, and added the following:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="food")
public class Food {
    // the other declarations remain
}
```

Comment: I followed your method and I was able to get the same xml out put, Retrieveing name, and description. But when I tried to do the same idea with mine I am not retrieving the second child element.